# How to add html menu in php

Tags: php, html

I made an HMTL menu and I want to add it to the page using PHP(I have some HTML and some PHP files).

If I use:

```
include('menu.html');
```

there is always something that isn't right.

So, how can I add the HTML menu using PHP? The menu must be on top, and the same as it is in HTML.

Comment: thats a lot of questions.And lot of answers needed!!! Be simple specific and on to the point.BTW Welcome to SO

Comment: When I include html menu in, it isn't the same as it is in html. It doesn't ruin just styling but everything...

Comment: I just want to use html menu in php, that will look the same as in html!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question about including html page in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230327/question-about-including-html-page-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this question: [Question about including html page in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230327/question-about-including-html-page-in-php)

If you have problems with the `.css` because they are included with `relative path` you need to set the `relative path` "`relative`" to the `.php` file

Comment: You're welcome. And welcome to Stackoverflow. If this doesn't solve your issue feel free to comment I will come back to this question later.

Comment: If it works and you are satisfied with an answer you can accept it and the one who gave you the answer will get reputation points for that (you will also receive 2 reputation points for doing this.)